# Like size and colour constancy, why does the brain not maintain focus constancy?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, vision

I have progressive myopia. I grew up with perfectly normal eyes but slowly started getting myopic.

The thing is, my brain knows (or *should* know) what the world looks like -- it knows that far away objects do not suddenly blur. So when the input from the retina changes, why doesn't the brain correct it in perception?

I'm assuming here that this should work by the same principles as size and colour constancy. In both cases the input from the retina is different but the brain doesn't perceive it as an actual change in size or colour.

Comment: The input is a blurry signal, what shall the brain do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I concur with @Chris. Color constancy and size constancy are neural mechanisms and can therefore be imposed on visual input from the retina. In contrast, a blurry input cannot be neurally improved. As an analogy: Visual perceptions are processed and rendered by the brain and therefore represent "photoshopped" perceptions. In other words, perceptions are subjective representations manufactured by higher-level visual processing. However, focus is determined by optics. An out-of-focus picture, to push the analogy, cannot be fixed by fotoshop, nor the brain.

Comment: Ps: sorry to hear about your visual disorder. Good luck.